# Google Maps JS 3 addGeoJson data layer callback when loaded

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I know the loadGeoJson function has a callback to ascertain when the layer has been loaded, but addGeoJson doesn't have this.

How would I check when all the features have been loaded using **addGeoJson**? I need to do this in order to then perform other functions on the data.

```
lyr_featured = new google.maps.Data({map:map});    
lyr_featured.addGeoJson(js_featured);
```

Comment: Not sure why this has a minus. Every time I explain in a question about research, someone comes along and edits it so I no longer bother. I only come to SO once I've exhaustively Googled the problem and tried lots of different coding.

Answer (score 0):

`addGeoJson` returns the imported features.

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/data#Data.addGeoJson):

> **addGeoJson**
>   addGeoJson(geoJson[, options])
>   **Parameters:**
>   **geoJson**:  Object
>   **options (optional)**:  Data.GeoJsonOptions
>   ***Return Value***:  `Array<Data.Feature>`
>   Adds GeoJSON features to the collection. Give this method a parsed JSON. ***The imported features are returned.*** Throws an exception if the GeoJSON could not be imported.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm not sure what you're getting at. The addGeoJson returns the features to the map, doesn't it? I don't think I can get access to them. Plus, I need to find out when all the points are added to the map. Can you illustrate a little more please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question that demonstrates what you want to use the data for if you want code.

Answer (score 0):

When using addGeoJson it returns an array of the features added to the map.

that means that:

```
let features = new google.maps.Data({map: yourMapElement}).addGeoJson(someGeoJsonData);
```

will give you an array with all the features you have added.
Console.log(features) to see it's structure, and reach information inside it.

Hope that's helpful.